# Console.log and Alert not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, servlets

im working in google chrome with servlet I have the following code:

```
public void process(String input, PrintWriter out)
  {
        System.out.println(input.indexOf("\\\\"));
        String Json[]= input.split("\\\\");
        for(int x =0; x< Json.length;x++)
        {
            System.out.println(Json.length);
            //JSONProcess(json[x]);
            out.println("<p class=\"json\" style =\"display:none\"> ");
            out.println(Json[x]);
            out.println("</p>");
        }
        out.println("<script>"+
                "var JSONProcess= function(){\n" +
                "var JsonInfo = document.getElementByClassName(\"json\");\n" +
                "var canvasEl = document.getElementById(\"c\");\n" +
                "var nodesData =[];\n"+

                "window.alert(\"This is a test\");\n" +
                "console.log(JsonInfo.length);\n"+
                "for(var i = 0;i<JsonInfo.length; i++)\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "var Json = JsonInfo[x].innerHTML;\n" +
                "if(Json.source == null)\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "nodesData.push([Json.x, Json.y, Json.r, Json.id]);\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "for(var i=0; i<nodesData.length; i++)\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "   var data = nodesData[i];\n" +
                "   console.log(data[1]);\n" +
                "   console.log(data[2]);\n" +
                "   console.log(data[3]);\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "}</script>");
  }
```

While the script tag throws no error, none of the console.log or alerts work. I tried

> delete window.log

Which was given as the answer to a previous ask of this question but that did nothing. The console is printing logs (i clicked on the funnel thing to check) and i have closed and reopened chrome. all the answers supplied in other versions of this question have not worked.

Comment: The `JSONProcess` function is never called, other than the commented line in the serverside script, which probably won't call a clientside function ?

Comment: oh my god im an idiot. you are right. if you put this as an answer ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call the function

```
 out.println("<script>"+
    "var JSONProcess= function(){\n" +
    "var JsonInfo = document.getElementByClassName(\"json\");\n" +
    "var canvasEl = document.getElementById(\"c\");\n" +
    "var nodesData =[];\n"+

    "window.alert(\"This is a test\");\n" +
    "console.log(JsonInfo.length);\n"+
    "for(var i = 0;i<JsonInfo.length; i++)\n" +
    "{\n" +
    "var Json = JsonInfo[x].innerHTML;\n" +
    "if(Json.source == null)\n" +
    "{\n" +
    "nodesData.push([Json.x, Json.y, Json.r, Json.id]);\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "for(var i=0; i<nodesData.length; i++)\n" +
    "{\n" +
    "   var data = nodesData[i];\n" +
    "   console.log(data[1]);\n" +
    "   console.log(data[2]);\n" +
    "   console.log(data[3]);\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "}" + 
    "JSONProcess()" + // here
    "</script>");
```

Note that printing javascript like this is not good practice, you'd be better of by putting the javascript in a .js file and just printing a single script tag with a source instead.

Comment: thanks its been a while since i have had to work with js